# Blurry Text until Mouse Hovers over?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Basically this is occurring in my theme: [Click here to view an example](http://i48.tinypic.com/2iv1wjs.png).

And it soon becomes crisp and clear when I hover my mouse over it. I noticed this problem started to occur when I added class elements to my html which is the following:

```
a.navigation{
    color: {color:text};
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}
a.navigation:hover:{
    color: {color:hover} !important;
    cursor: crosshair;
    text-decoration:none;
}
<a href="/" class="navigation">Entries</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/ask" class="navigation">Message</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/archive" class="navigation">Records<a/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/rss" class="navigation">Feed</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/theme" class="navigation">Theme</a>
```

Any ideas why this link might be affecting my other links in my theme? Thanks so much. Sorry if this is a beginners question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but your css has a few mistakes:

```
a.navigation{
color: {color:text};
font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
text-transform:lowercase;
letter-spacing:2px;
}
a.navigation:hover:{
color: {color:hover} !important;
cursor: crosshair;
text-decoration:none;
```

what is this `color: {color:text};` and `color: {color:hover} !important;` ??? 
It should be `color: blue;` for example.

and there is another ":" in here `a.navigation:hover:{`. It should be `a.navigation:hover{`
And you forgot to close `a.navigation:hover{ }`

Please reply if it helped

```
a.navigation{
    color: blue;
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}

a.navigation:hover{
    color: red !important;
    cursor: crosshair;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

​

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to mention that {color:text} is used for tumblr only. And you are right i did make a mistake on a.navigation:hover, so I will go fix that. I fixing the mistakes but it didn't work! Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `color: {color:hover}` is valid css. You might want to start there.

Comment: It is valid when using tumblr.